# Can you use os.path.exists() on a file that starts with a number?

Tags: python, path, os.path

I have a set of files named `16ID_#.txt` where `#` represents a number. I want to check if a specific file number exists, using [`os.path.exists()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.exists), before attempting to import the file to python. When I put together my variable for the folder where the files are, with the name of the file (e.x.: `folderpath+"\16ID_#.txt"`), python interprets the `"\16"` as a music note.

Is there any way I can prevent this, so that `folderpath+"\16ID_#.txt"` is interpreted as I want it to be?

I cannot change the names of the files, they are output by another program over which I have no control.

Comment: Simply double up the `\`: `folderpath+"\\16ID_#.txt"` or use a raw string: `folderpath+r"\16ID_#.txt"`.

Comment: Have a look at this: https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals

Answer (score 4):

You can use `/` to build paths, regardless of operating system, but the correct way is to use `os.path.join`:

```
os.path.exists(os.path.join(folderpath, "16ID_#.txt"))
```

Answer (score 2):

I get these are windows \paths. Maybe the problem is that you need to escape the backslash, because `\16` could be interpreted as a special code. So maybe you need to put `\\16` instead of `\16`.